# Быстрый разбор txt файла на строки и столбцы

Tags: c, strtok

Посоветуйте, как **наиболее быстро** загрузить и разбить данные на строки и столбцы

```
char *buf = NULL;
char * row;
char * val;

int main(void)
{
    buf = get_file_contents(DBNAME); // Грузит весь файл в пямять
    row = strtok (buf,"\n"); //взять позицию до 1го \n
    while (row != NULL)
    {
          val = strtok (row, "|"); 
          do {
             printf ("%s\n",val); //тут ptr(val) думаю копировать в data[x][y++], и потом менять разделитель | на \0 в памяти, можно так? )
             val = strtok (NULL, "|");
          } while (val);

          //внутренний strtok сбрасывает внешний, поэтому не работает...
          row = strtok (NULL,"\n");
          /*x++;y=0;*/
    }
}
```

Внутренний `strtok` все портит, как сделать, без лишних копирований строки?

**UPDATE:**
Для разбора строк вида id|title||value (С пустыми значениями), использовал strchr:

```
static void
print_tokens1( char * s)
{
    char * ptr1;
    ptr1 = s;

    char * tok = strchr( ptr1, '|' );
    while( tok )
    {
        *tok = 0;
        printf( "%s\n", ptr1 );
        ptr1 = tok + 1;        
        tok = strchr( ptr1, '|' );
    }

    if (*ptr1) 
    {
        printf( "%s\n", ptr1 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void
print_tokens( char * s )
{
    char * tok = strtok( s, "|" );
    while( tok )
    {
        printf( "%s ", tok );
        tok = strtok( NULL, "|" );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}

int main()
{
    char * newline;
    char * ptr;
    char * content = get_file_contents( DBNAME );
    ptr = content;

    newline = strchr( ptr, '\n' );
    while( newline )
    {
        *newline = 0;
        print_tokens( ptr );
        ptr = newline + 1;
        newline = strchr( ptr, '\n' );
    }

    if( *ptr )
    {
        print_tokens( ptr );
    }

    free( content );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как определяет конец токена strtok - модифицирует исходную строку или копирует токен?
К тому, что для большей скорости, лучше вообще отказатся от strtok, в пользу strchr?

Comment: `strtok()` лепит нули прямо в исходную строку когда встретит нужный символ. А что быстрей - тестировать надо. Теоретически `strchr()` должен быть быстрей, если нужно искать всего один символ. Но что прямо так ОЧЕНЬ быстрей - не уверен :)

Comment: При такой строке не работает  - 1|title||value, подскажите в чем дело? пустые строки неразбирает - 

    n=0;
    while( tok )
    {
        printf( "%d = %s\n", n, tok );
        switch (n) {
               case 0:X[idx-1].id = atoi(tok);break;
               case 1:X[idx-1].title = tok;break;
               case 2:X[idx-1].tags = tok;break;
               case 3:X[idx-1].value = tok;break;
        }
        n++;
    }

В итоге value кладется нетуда - X[idx-1].tags; Непонятно, как работает while - после пустого значения tags он должен остановится, а он идет далше, пропуская пустые значения?

Comment: Проблема в особенностях `strtok()`, которая проскочит последовательность `||`. Убедиться в этом просто (вот что бы самостоятельно не сделать это? под отладчиком же всё прекрасно видно):

    char s[] = "a|b||c";
    print_tokens( s );

Вывод: менять `strtok()` на что-то своё. Правда, судя по именам, менять надо инструменты целиком :)

Comment: В `SEE ALSO` в `man strtok` можно найти `strsep`.

    NOTES
       The strsep() function was introduced as a  replacement  for   strtok(3),
       since  the  latter cannot handle empty fields.  However, strtok(3) con‐
       forms to C89/C99 and hence is more portable.

Похоже, это ваш случай, но обратите внимание на раздел `BUGS` в `man strsep`. В принципе, ничего принципиально нового, по сравнению с `strtok/strtok_r`. 

Резюме - надо семь раз подумать, пользоваться ими или писать свое, видимо основываясь на `strchr/strpbrk/strspn/strcspn/` для обработки разделителей.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы. 
сделал с помощью strchr, вверху отписал код.
з.ы. что не так с именами? Строго не судите, это 1е что делаю на с )